# Creating multiple inner buffers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, polygon-creation, multiple

How can I create a multiple inner (negative) buffer of a polygon layer that starts from an initial distance and repeats n times at a fixed distance?

The result should be independent polygons.
Ex: I would like to generate 10 independent interior polygons relative to a layer of polygon features, the first of them 30m apart, and then 9 more interior polygons 1m apart.

Comment: Hi David, welcome to GIS SE. Please not that this is an english-language site and all contributions have to be in english, otherwise the question risks to be closed/deleted. Use an automatic translation software if you have troubles writing in english. A solution to your problem is using negative buffers with Geoemtry Generator/Geomtry by expression.

Comment: A diagram to explain what you want to achieve would be a valuable addition to your question. By independent, do you mean they are (30 and) 1 m strips, or are they progressively getting 1 m wider, but all starting at the boundary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use `Menu Processing > Toolbox > Geometry by expression` with this expression:

```
   collect_geometries (
       array_foreach (
           generate_series (30,39,1),
           buffer ($geometry, -@element)
       )
   )
```

2. Run `Menu Vector > Geometry tools > Multipart to singleparts`:

**Remark:** Line 3 in the above expression contains the distances for the bufers: 30 is the initial distance for the first buffer; 39 is the distance of the last buffer (from 30 to 39, you get 10 elements), 1 is the distance between each buffer (here, for the value of `1`, this is optional).

*The solution, here demonstrated with Geometry Generator:*
[image]